# reloadData not getting called

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios, uitableview

I am updating my table data resource and then I am calling

[self.tableView reloadData]

to load the table view with this new data. This is all happening in a thread. Now, it works fine with lets say I add 4-5 objects but at some point it stops calling the cellForRowAtIndexPath to reload the table with new data.

Data source is getting updated all the time to contain latest data. So, data source has 10 objects but I can see only 5 on the screen. And it keeps on adding the data but do not show it. Breakpoint shows the call to reloadData is not invoking cellForRowAtIndexPath after that.

What could be the reason.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

hunch: make sure you message UIKit objects from the main thread (exclusively).